# Error: contract violation in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm practicing recursion in Scheme. My code below is used to take a pattern clause and a statement then return a list of bindings if statement match pattern, false if it isn't:

```
(define remove-question-mark
  (lambda (s1)
    (if (memq #\? (string->list (symbol->string s1)))
        (cdr (string->list (symbol->string s1)))
        '())))

(define check-two-symbol
  (lambda (symbol1 symbol2)
    (if (and (regexp-match #rx#"\\?attrs" (symbol->string symbol1)) (list? symbol2))
        (cons symbol1 (list symbol2))
        (if (equal? symbol1 symbol2)
            '()
            (if (equal? (remove-question-mark symbol1) (string->list (symbol->string symbol2)))
                (cons symbol1 symbol2)
                #f)))))

(define clause
  (lambda (state1 state2)
    (if (and (null? (car state1)) (null? (car state2)))
        '() 
        (list (check-two-symbol (car state1) (car state2)) (clause (cdr state1) (cdr state2))))))
```

This is my input:

```
(clause '(wasDerivedFrom ?der ?e1 ?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(wasDerivedFrom der e1 e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
```

I got this error from my code:

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '()
```

Expected output:

```
((?der . der)
(?e1 . e1)
(?e2 . e2)
(?attrs_derv (prov:type "Revision")))
```

After debugging, i found that error happens when `(car state1)` is `?attrs_derv`

If I run function `check-two-symbol` seperrately, like `(check-two-symbol '?attrs-derv '(prov:type "Revision"))`, it prints out nicely:

```
(?attrs_derv (prov:type "Revision"))
```

But with the main function, i get error. So can someone please help me show how to fix this error?? I'm not really familiar with recursion much ....

Thank in advanced!

Comment: Take a look at [Using scheme/racket to return specific items from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17312128/1281433) where a user encounters the same error message.

Comment: In `clause`, shouldn't `(and … (car (null? state2)))` be `(and … (null? (car state2)))`?

Comment: It should be `(and (null? state1) (null? state2))`, isn't it??

Comment: I don't know what it's _supposed_ to be for your code to work correctly, but `(car (null? ...))` will cause errors eventually (`and` is short-circuiting, so you're not seeing them yet) because `null?` returns `#t` or `#f` and you can't take the `car` of those.

Comment: Ooops, the `(car (null?....))` was a typo. i'm really sorry for that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that you're calling `car` with something that's not a pair.  You only call `car` in four places, so it's one of those in `clause`.  Now `clause` is only called *from* `clause`, so you don't have to go too far to track this down.  What sort of values should `clause` be called with?  When you call `clause` recursively (last line of the following code), you're calling it with `(cdr state1)` and `(cdr state2)`.  Is there any reason to assume that those aren't `'()`?

```
(define clause
  (lambda (state1 state2)
    (if (and (null? (car state1)) (car (null? state2)))
        '() 
        (list (check-two-symbol (car state1) (car state2))
              (clause (cdr state1) (cdr state2))))))
                      ------------ ------------
```

Let's look at what `clause` gets called with from your initial input:

```
(clause '(wasDerivedFrom ?der ?e1 ?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(wasDerivedFrom der e1 e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
(clause '(?der ?e1 ?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(der e1 e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
(clause '(?e1 ?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(e1 e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
(clause '(?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
(clause '?attrs_derv '((prov:type "Revision")))
```

At this point you're going to try to call `car` on `?attrs_derv`, and that should cause an error, because a symbol isn't a pair. Indeed, if we simplify `clause` to the following (so that it doesn't call `check-two-symbol`)

```
(define clause
  (lambda (state1 state2)
    (if (and (null? (car state1)) (car (null? state2)))
        '() 
        (list (clause (cdr state1) (cdr state2))))))
```

and then try to call the code you mentioned, we get an error:

```
> (clause '(wasDerivedFrom ?der ?e1 ?e2 . ?attrs_derv) '(wasDerivedFrom der e1 e2 (prov:type "Revision")))
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '?attrs_derv
```

The fact that you got a different error means that either that call to `check-two-symbol` makes a call to `car` somewhere that we don't see, or that the test you showed us didn't line up with the output you showed us.  In either case, it looks like you're trying to recurse down two lists in parallel.  You're only going to be able to do this if they're both pairs, so you probably want code like

```
(if (not (and (pair? state1) (pair? state2)))
   <then-something>
   <else-something>)
```

Comment: I think I shouldn't call (car state1) and (car state2) in if condition, because it has been handled when if statement return false,  am i correct ??

Comment: @TrungBún It's not clear what your code is _supposed_ to do.  `clause` isn't a particularly meaningful name, and there are no comments.  We can't say what would make it correct, since we don't know what it's _ought_ to do.  That said, if you're going to call `car` and `cdr` on the states, you could probably check that they satisfy `pair?`.

Comment: I fixed it and I got it running!!!! :) The problem was at `(car (null?....)` thank you very much for pointing it out!! Really !!